# Threading parameters

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, thread-sleep

Again a question from me.. having some issues again. Hope to find someone who's a lot smarter and knows this.. :D

I'm now having the issue with threading that when opening threading urls in a range of (1,1000), I would love to see actually all the different urls. Only when i run the code i get a lot of double variables (probably because the crawls go that fast). Anyway this is my code: I try to see at which Thread it is, but I get doubles.

```
import threading
import urllib2
import time
import collections

results2 = []
def crawl():
    var_Number = thread.getName().split("-")[1]
    try:
        data = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.waarmaarraar.nl").read()
        results2.append(var_Number)
    except:
        crawl()

threads = []

for n in xrange(1, 1000):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=crawl)
    thread.start()  
    threads.append(thread)

# to wait until all three functions are finished
print "Waiting..."

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print "Complete."

# print results (All numbers, should be 1/1000)
results2.sort()
print results2    
# print doubles (should be [])
print [x for x, y in collections.Counter(results2).items() if y > 1]
```

However, if I add time.sleep(0.1) directly under the xrange line, those doubles will not occur. Although this does slow my programm down a lot. Anyone knows a better way to fix this?

Comment: why do you care what thread requested the url? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to crawl the page like this way: http://waarmaarraar.nl/page/1/, page/2/, page/3/ , but with my code I get some doubles when I don't add the time.sleep

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on [Thread.getName()](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.getName) it is a correct behavior.

If you want an unique name for each of your thread you have to set it using the [name attribute](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.name).

Based on what you expect in the end, replacing

```
for n in xrange(1, 1000):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=crawl)
    thread.start()  
    threads.append(thread)
```

with

```
for n in xrange(1, 1000):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=crawl)
    thread.name = n
    thread.start()  
    threads.append(thread)
```

and `var_Number = thread.getName().split("-")[1]` with `var_Number = thread.name` should help you.

**EDIT**
After some testing a user-custom name can be reused by another thread, so the only way to pass `n` will be to use the `args` or `kwargs` of [`threading.Thread()`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#threading.Thread).
This behavior make sense, if we need to use some sort of data in a Thread, pass it correctly don't try to put it where it don't belong.

Comment: Same problem, I get doubles.. Run1: = ['58', '88', '81', '63', '16', '42', '78'], Run2:  ['43', '80', '86', '84', '22', '46', '29', '82', '4', '8', '97', '74', '71', '94', '11', '77', '13', '18', '36', '88'], in a Range of 100.

Comment: @user1250201 Right, I made some testing and update the answer with a new solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a recursive call to `crawl()` in the exception handler. The same thread runs the function several times if there is an error. Thus `results2` may contain the same `var_Number` several times. If you add `time.sleep(.1)` (a pause); your script consumes less resources e.g., number of open fds, running threads and the request to the remote server is more likely to succeed.

Also default thread names may repeat. If a thread exited; another thread may have the same name e.g., if the implementation uses `.ident` attribute to generate a name.

Notes:

- use [pep-8 naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You could use pep8, pyflakes, epylint command-line tools to check your code automatically
- you don't need 1000 threads to fetch 1000 urls (see [my comment to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772464/error-with-threading-python#comment17262941_12772464))
- it is not nice to generate requests without a pause to the same site.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for all your comments (also in the other posts). I tried your way, but i'm not that good with it that I managed to succesfully try all your tips. Still, I do feel that my old way is the fastest way. (It did +- 30377 URLS in 5 minutes, untill I got the 'error: can't start new thread'.